# all occurences of each line from a file in another file for each line in the first file

Tags: code-golf, string

This is a code golf problem: Say you have two files, one file s and one  file h. The problem is that for each line l of s you should produce a list that contains all lines of h that contain l. By "contain" I mean a substring, so, for example the line "foobar12baz" contains either foo, bar, foobar, 12, 1 or baz, etc...

You may use any programming language or any program to accomplish this in the least number of characters possible. Instead of a list you may print an array, or other sequence type structure.

Here is some Haskell I wrote that does it in 103 characters, and assumes you have the following modules imported

Data.List

Control.Monad

Control.Applicative

```
let f = (<$>) lines . readFile in (\(a,b)-> [[d|d<-b, isInfixOf c d]|c<-a]) <$> liftM2 (,) (f "s") (f "h")
```

Example files:

"h"

```
asdf1
asd2asdf
s3adsf
```

"s"

```
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
[["asdf1"],["asd2asdf"],["s3adsf"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Wes. And again, welcome to CodeGolf.SE.

Answer (score 9):

just grep is enough...

```
grep -Ff s h
```

Answer (score 1):

Better:

```
puts IO.readlines('h').grep /#{IO.readlines's'}/
```

In ruby, 53 characters, outputs an array and not a file:

```
p IO.readlines('h').each{|m|m=~/#{IO.readlines's'}/}
```

This reads file 'h' for every line of 's' to save a variable. Not ideal.

Happy golfing!

Answer (score -1):

```
while read -r;do grep "$REPLY" --h>"$REPLY";done<s
```

YEAAAAAAAH!!1